# Extract first character of each word from the sentence string

Tags: python, string

I need to make a code that when you enter a text it takes the first letter from each word in the sentence you placed.

For example, for sample string `"I like to play guitar and piano and drums"`, it should print `"Iltpgapad"`

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
line = "I like to play guitar and piano and drums"
words = line.split()
letters = [word[0] for word in words]
print "".join(letters)
```

Answer (score 4):

This snippet is compatible with Python 3.x:

```
print(''.join([x[0] for x in raw_input("Enter text:").split()]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
line = "I like to play guitar and piano and drums"
letters = ""
words = line.split()
for word in words:
    letters = letters + word[0]
print(" ".join(letters).upper())
```